# Rotate book in html using css and javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css, 3d, rotation

I am trying to animate a complete book image both front and back in such a manner, that it gives the impression of a book, also when I hover on it, the book should rotate, giving me the back of the book. I have tried numerous attempts, but every time there is a browser incompatibility issue, some show the right output others don't...

[image]

This should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Alright, and what have you tried so far to solve this problem?

Comment: well i tried .. using this plug-in http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/3D-Cover-Flip-Animations-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transforms-Cover3D/

Comment: it works perfectly on chrome .. but for some mozilla browsers the edge is missing... i don't know the reason

Comment: it is working on mozilla version 48.0 .. but does not work accordingly in version 50

Answer (score 0):

strange but I think it will work:
please change angle in transform: (-90 to -89)

```
.Cover3D div.left{
transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 14px );
}
```

to

```
.Cover3D div.left{
transform: rotateY( -89deg ) translateZ( 14px );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input bro .. but the output is same as before.. for some reason the edges of the book are not getting displayed in some browsers (mozilla version 50)

Comment: it worked ... but instead of going from -90deg to -89deg ... i had to go from -90deg to -91deg ...so thanks for the input ..Also is one little issue left i.e, the book shrinks like 1% when  it rotates completely...